# How do I show the keyboard by default in UITextView?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I want to create a view that consists solely of a `UITextView`. When the view is first shown, by default, I'd like the keyboard to be visible and ready for text entry. This way, the user does not have to touch the `UITextView` first in order to begin editing.

Is this possible? I see the class has a notification called `UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification` but I'm not sure how to send that, or if that is even the right approach.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

to accomplish that just send the becomeFirstResponder message to your UITextField, as follows (assuming you have an outlet called textField, pointing to the field in question):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: I just found this. For me viewWillAppear doesn't work but viewDidAppear seems to do the job!

Answer (score 19):

## In Swift

To automatically show the keyboard, to the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // show keyboard
    textView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

**Notes**

- This assumes that the text view is editable.
- Works for both `UITextView` and `UITextField`
- To hide the keyboard use `textView.resignFirstResponder()`

Answer (score 6):

Following worked fine for me using Swift

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Show keyboard by default
    billField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Key is to use the viewDidAppear function.