# Show iPhone keyboard programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, uitextview, iphone-softkeyboard

I want show the iphone keyboard. How can I write the code (programmatically) to show the keyboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259819/how-do-i-show-the-keyboard-by-default-in-uitextview

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Jacob said, you'll have to run `becomeFirstResponder` on a `UITextView` to make it the first responder, the object the user's currently working with. If you do this, the iPhone OS automatically shows the keyboard, cause that's what's needed for working with a `UITextView` from a user perspective.

Answer (score 9):

As others have noted, you send the `becomeFirstResponder` message to the control that you want the keyboard to edit.

One extra thing you should be aware of is that if you plug an external keyboard into an iPad then the keyboard will not appear on screen. You need to design your view so it doesn't look silly without the on-screen keyboard.