# Setting a UITextField into editing mode programmatically

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITextField` that I want to set into editing mode (keyboard on screen and cursor in text field box) programatically.  I know that the user will be in editing mode when this view appears onscreen, so I want to save the user from having to tap the text field.

The "editing" property of a `UITextField` is read only - so that doesn't work.  Is there a way to set the `UITextField` into editing mode, with a keyboard onscreen, programmatically?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Call `becomeFirstResponder` on the UITextField.

Related question:
[How do I show the keyboard by default in UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259819/how-do-i-show-the-keyboard-by-default-in-uitextview)

Comment: I found this to be unreliable unless I made sure to run it in the main thread:

dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[textView becomeFirstResponder];});

Answer (score 28):

You have to call `[textField becomeFirstResponder]`;

Comment: You probably posted this seconds too late, and you got no upvotes, so I decided to give you the upvote you deserve. :)

Comment: I gave you the upvote because using brackets and semicolon.

Answer (score 12):

Indeed call `[textField becomeFirstResponder]` in Obj-C or `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` in Swift.

**However, make sure you call this in the `viewDidAppear` and not in the `viewDidLoad` to prevent strange behaviour (see: [When set UITextField as FirstResponder programmatically, cause some weird actions on text editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899851/when-set-uitextfield-as-firstresponder-programmatically-cause-some-weird-action)).**