# When set UITextField as FirstResponder programmatically, cause some weird actions on text editing

Tags: ios, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

I have a UITextField with custom keyboard, basically like a calculator. I would like my keyboard show up by default, so i used `[self.topInputTextField becomeFirstResponder];` in `viewDidLoad`, I think that's very common usage. However, it causes some very weird actions on my textfield.

When i set my textfield as the first responder in viewDidLoad, and every time after i done editing, the text will jump, and when i click another text field and and click the first text field again, the texts in the first text field sometimes shift down and disappear, but sometimes not. I feel it's very hard to describe, so i recorded a GIF image for it.

[image]

And the reason, that I am sure `[self.topInputTextField becomeFirstResponder];` causing the issue, is when i comment that line of code out, everything back to normal. here is the GIF after i comment out that line:

[image]

that's vert strange to me, between 2 GIF file, the only change i did is comment out that line of code. I couldn't find any solution on SE. Any idea would be very appreciated.

**Edit:**
    One more thing is I tried to change font, and font sizes, they all have similar strange behaviors.

*Edit 2:**
    here is how i set up my textfield,i didn't do anything fancy

[image]

Comment: could you include some more information about the size of the text fields? and how they are setup in the view controller or nib file?

Comment: better if you provide part of your code for the same.

Comment: sure i will add some more screen shot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling the keyboard in `viewDidAppear`, this method gets called after `viewDidLoad`. I assume it's because you should only call the keyboard on a loaded view that has appeared to the user, so if you call it before the view actually appears it will cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: A view probably can't become responder before it's visible because it's not yet part of the responder chain

Comment: Bless your Soul for this answer, mysterious Chicken Man.

Answer (score 4):

viewDidLoad is too early for calling this, the UI hasn't worked out which size your screen is, or even which orientation your device is in.  It isn't yet a UI really...  Try it in willAppearAnimated:  ..

Comment: Did you try both `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: @Chicken actually just tried viewDidAppear, it solved this issue.. viewWillAppear will not.. can you add that as the answer, and would you mind to explain a little bit?

Comment: Jef's reasoning was correct, the actual drawing of UI wasn't finalised in viewDidLoad. Thanks :)

Comment: well thats about the cheapest 15 points you'll ever win on stack ya pirate :p    bravo

Comment: @chicken no hard feelings whatsoever, a joke is all mate