# How to add a clickable label around UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a `UIView` with a `UILabel` and a `UITextField`:

```
+--------------+
| label        |
|              |
| +-----------+|
| | textField ||
| +-----------+|
+--------------+
```

I want to select or focus the `textField` when I touch the `label`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your container `UIView` to a `UIControl` and in your `ViewController.viewDidLoad` add the following:

```
    textFieldContainer.addTarget(textField,
      action: #selector(becomeFirstResponder),
      for: .touchUpInside)
```

This will cause a `touchUpInside` event on the `textFieldContainer` to focus the `textField`

Comment: Or use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` with your container view.

Comment: @rmaddy in terms of simplicity, wouldn't this be a better choice than a GestureRecog?

Comment: @Jay It is not as clean. The ammount of code adding a UITapGestureRecognizer is sameish, but you get the benefits of being able to handle multiple gestures and having more control in the same view while the code being more clean and readable.

Answer (score 1):

1: [Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `UILabel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829151/swift3-ios-how-to-make-uitapgesturerecognizer-trigger-function) or your `UIView` as you wish

2: and handle the action from the tapGesture to fire [start editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130695/setting-a-uitextfield-into-editing-mode-programatically) the textfield on tap.

Don't forget to set the UILabel to [userInteractionEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilabel/1620543-userinteractionenabled?changes=latest_beta&language=objc) = **true** if you add the tap gesture to the label.